# Pegex grammar design

Tags: perl, pegex

Need parse text like the following:

```
optional free text
@somemacro1( optional free text
        @somemacro2(SOME TEXT)@ or other optional free text
)@
another free text
```

e.g. it is basically very simple:

- the source is an free text
- which could contain some macros in a form `@MACRONAME(` *some content* `)@`
- the *some content* is again an free text which could contain some macro - e.g. the macros could be nested (see the above example)
- the result of the parsed macro is some string (based on the macro name)

I want learn [Pegex](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Pegex/lib/Pegex.pod) so decided to use it for this task.

**The question is: could someone help me with the Pegex-grammar for the above?**

Is someone wondering what i already tried, here is my test source - isn't working. :(

```
package Rec {
    use 5.014;
    use warnings;
    use base 'Pegex::Receiver';
    use Data::Dumper;

    sub gotrule {
        my($self, $got) = @_;
        say "Got rule:", $self->{rule};
        return "GOT" . $self->{rule} . "RULE";
    }
}

use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Pegex::Parser;
use Pegex::Grammar;

my $source = <<'EOF';
free text
@somemacro1( optional free text
    @somemacro2(SOME TEXT)@ or other optional free text
)@
another free text
EOF

my $grammar_text = do {local $/; <DATA>};
my $grammar = Pegex::Grammar->new(text => $grammar_text);
my $receiver = Rec->new;
my $parser = Pegex::Parser->new( grammar => $grammar, receiver => $receiver);
my $input = Pegex::Input->new(string => $source);
my $ret = $parser->parse($input);

__DATA__
%grammar test
%version 0.0.1

start:      seq*

seq:        | macro
        | text

macro:      / AT macro-name LPAREN content RPAREN AT /
macro-name: / WORD+ /
text:       / ALL* /
content:    / ALL* /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. It is tricky since your text is arbitrary, so you have to use the `got_*` methods in your `Rec` receiver class to work through it. You can see my comment on how to debug Pegex grammars too. I use the `XXX` module to dump the data neatly as should you for Pegex debugging. Here is the sample code that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
package Rec {
    use 5.014;
    use warnings;
    use Pegex::Base;
    extends 'Pegex::Tree';

    use XXX;

    sub got_comment {}

    sub got_text {
        my ($self, $got) = @_;
        return $self->flatten($got);
    }
    sub got_macro {
        my ($self, $got) = @_;
        return $got;
    }
    sub final {
        my($self, $got) = @_;
        XXX $got;
    }
}

use 5.014;
use warnings;
use XXX;
use Pegex::Parser;
use Pegex::Grammar;

my $source = <<'EOF';
free text
@somemacro1( optional free text
    @somemacro2(SOME TEXT)@ or other optional free text
)@
another free text
EOF

my $grammar_text = do {local $/; <DATA>};
my $grammar = Pegex::Grammar->new(text => $grammar_text);
my $receiver = Rec->new;
my $parser = Pegex::Parser->new( grammar => $grammar, 
       receiver => $receiver,
       debug => 1); ### NOTE USE THIS FOR DEBUGGING
my $ret = $parser->parse($source);
__DATA__
%grammar test
%version 0.0.1

start: seq* end-of-seq

end-of-seq: - EOS
seq: comment | macro | text

comment: blank-line
macro-stop: - / RPAREN AT / -
macro-start: - macro-name -
macro: macro-start macro-content* macro-stop
macro-content: (comment | macro | text)
macro-name: / AT ( WORD+ ) LPAREN /
text: - / (!macro-start) ([ WORDS ]+) / -
blank-line: /- EOL/
```

Comment: Ah YES!  The main trick is the `(!macro-start)` - really cool. Somehow - i understand every pegex grammar what i read - but i'm unable invent them myself. Really thanx, for the other comments too! +10 if i could - especially for the new StackOverflow user ;) :).

Comment: If you have further `Pegex` questions please visit **#pegex** channel on Freenode IRC.